# while True loop in async stops other parts of code from working Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot.

What my discord bot does *listens to messages throughout the server and prints it real-time.*

However, I also want the code to constantly recieve input from me from the console and print it out in a particular server ID. The following is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Prints message


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Execute on-ready stuff
    while True:
        kb = input(">>>")

        #Delivers the message into a certain channel
```

The problem is after the while True loop is executed, the other `on_message` functions stop working. I have seen other similar questions but I don't understand the async functions.

Could someone tell me how to both receive input continuously and print out incoming messages real-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in `while True`, the problem is in the built-in `input` function, which is blocking and not async. Asyncio is based on cooperative multi-tasking, which means that your coroutine must choose to allow other code to run by *awaiting* something. Since your `while` loop doesn't await anything, it blocks everything else.

Look into the [aioconsole](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole) package which provides an async version of `input`.

Comment: This is actually also the same reason why you shouldn't use ```time.sleep``` in your async functions, but rather ```asyncio.sleep```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494798/keeeping-the-loop-going-until-input-discord-py/54501622#54501622

Comment: Yes, the answer is an example of using it with `discord.py`

Comment: @Benjin I meant, _this_ answer already points to aioconsole. If you think the other answer is relevant, you might want to link it in a comment to the question, or even mark the question as duplicate of the previous one.