# Get input from the terminal, and send it into a channel in discord.py

Tags: python, input, discord.py

I have spent a decent amount of time trying to found some solution to this, as far as I am aware, no one has asked or done this online. So what I want is to get user input FROM THE TERMINAL, and then send in into a channel I specify(I don't need to change channels), and for getting the chat, I don't know how to print what the other users are saying, I don't really to build commands into it, I am not that experienced with Discord.py as I am with Discord.Js, but I don't want to do this in discord.js. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keeeping the loop going until input (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494798/keeeping-the-loop-going-until-input-discord-py)

Comment: After I am home, i'll try it, but if it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by creating a function to handle messages from the console:

```
@client.event
async def sendFromConsole():
    run = True
    while run:
      message = input('Enter message: ')
      channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
      await channel.send(message)
```

This repeatedly asks for your input in the console and will send the string to the desired channel. (Be sure to call this function from your on_ready function beforehand)

Comment: Ok, ill try it.

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't run

Comment: https://replit.com/@IdkDwij/discordbottypehi#main.py

Comment: and i cant find the right indent to print the message content, but i can print stuff about the message if you could help with that

Comment: i forgot to call the function :skull: